# Where dependencies tab been moved in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In old versions of android studio there was a tab where I was able to add dependency from IDE
[image]

Now there is no such tab. Where its been moved to?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer on your screenshot. They have moved it to sidebar, so you can click the "Dependencies" there and then choose a module to see his dependencies or add a new one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: cool. thank you. im dumb lol xD